# Get by DOC_ID only with Firestore REST API

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using Firebase REST API to get documents. Now the following url works fine:

`https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project}/databases/(default)/documents/{collection}/{doc_id}`

However I'd like to know if it's possible to get a document only with {doc_id} without specifying the collection?

Thanks so much!

Comment: What is the exact reason for such requirement? Knowing it will help answering your question. In any case, Firestore Documents MUST be within a Collection, that's the way the database is structured. Maybe you want to query several documents with the same ID within different collections?

Comment: Using their cloud function you can basically do `->collections()->document($id)->snapshot()` without specifying the collection. I would like to keep that 'all collections' functionality within my code.

Comment: Could you be more precise? Are you speaking about a Cloud Function trigger path and wildcards? https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters

Comment: I want something like this:
https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/projects/{project}/databases/(default)/documents/**ALL_COLLECTIONS**/{doc_id}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the Firestore REST API, you will not be able to query the database for all documents with a specific ID under all possible collections. This will not be possible with the other SDKs as well.

What you could do with the REST API is listing all the (sub-)collections of a given document, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases.documents/listCollectionIds?authuser=0. You will receive `collectionIds` array of Collections IDs and you will be able to iterate on this array to search for all the documents with a specific ID within those collections.

Note that it doesn't seem to be possible to list the top-level collections for the database.